# Get zsh segmentation fault when doing the KALP-15 tutorial with Gromacs. I using macOS Catalina. How can overcome this problem?

Tags: zsh

I'm using Gromacs to run the KALP-15 tutorial. 
When I run gmx genrestr -f KALP_newbox.gro -o strong_posre.itp -fc 10000 10000 10000
 I get
 Reading structure file Select group to position restrain
 zsh: segmentation fault gmx genrestr -f KALP_newbox.gro -o strong_posre.itp -fc 10000 10000 10000

Comment: I am using a MAC with Catalina os

Comment: @RThomas : I don't see how this problem is related to Zsh, since you get a segmentation fault **gmx**. I don't know the gmx command, but if this does a SEGV, you need to tag it with _gromacs_ or contact the [gromacs support](http://www.gromacs.org/Support),